# Validation Error how to move screen to error message

Tags: 2013, custom-form, form, list-form, validation

Currently on my SP site when a user submits/edits a form and a column validation error occurs the screen refreshes but stays where it is (so if you have scrolled to the bottom it refreshes you at the bottom).

This is confusing for users as they do not know that the submission had failed.

Is there a way to take the user to the first instance of an error message or for a popup/other message to occur to inform the user of an error?

Comment: InfoPath form or SharePoint List Item form?

Comment: SharePoint List Item form

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: No unfortunately. I ended up putting a brief message at the bottom of the form and used JS alert() for the most common errors - in this case it was leaving a field empty.